# Copying code from Private Sub to Shared Sub

Tags: vb.net, shared

I'm trying to have a bunch of code run on the hour every hour in my VB Application. The code works in it's own Sub, but when I add it to this "TopOfTheHour" Shared Sub I get the error "cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

I left in the loadlbl.Visible as an example of what doesn't work which is just a label control on my main Form (Form1). Writing the refresh time to the console works, but loadlbl.Visible = True does not.

```
    Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer = CType(source, System.Timers.Timer)
    aTimer.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine("Server Status Refreshed at " & DateTime.Now)
    loadlbl.Visible = True
    'Far more code is here, much of it with the same error.
    aTimer.Interval = MillisecondsToNextTopOfTheHour()
    aTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

All my code for Form 1 (including what I want to add to this Shared Sub) is [here](http://pastebin.com/nfGFyqLX) on PasteBin. (VB Syntax Highlighting is on so code is easier to read)

Thank You!

Comment: the error means what it says.  if the sub is Shared/static you cant reference objects which only exist at runtime including labels such as (apparently) `loadLbl`.  Remove the Shared modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need this method to be 'shared'? Remove the shared and try again.

Shared means that is method is not an instance method, it has no access to any local variables.

Comment: Plutonix is right - I did not see this answer while editing my anser in the webpage.

Comment: Thanks! I thought removing shared stopped the test MsgBox from displaying, but it seems the MsgBox was just appearing under another window I had open. Thanks again.